# How to read in tableau (twbx) file into python?

Tags: python, tableau-api

I would like to produce some custom output with python with data from Tableau files. I dont have access to the Tableau server to run the 'Tabpy' library.

Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the following link useful.
https://community.tableau.com/thread/152463

One of the posts in the thread mentioned the following which is worth exploring:

> If you're looking to generate a TWBX dynamically, you should rename
>   your .twbx file to .zip, extract the contents and you can do whatever
>   you want with those in Python to dynamically create or adjust a
>   workbook file. The structure / definition of the workbook file is just
>   XML so no special code needed to read and parse that.

Comment: This led me down a rabbit hole, that I found the answer too. Tableau 10.X and later go to Data> find what source you want data from at the bottom > click 'Export Data to CSV'